# Official circuit for paddle?

Tags: rules

Is there an official, international circuit of tournaments (like ATP/WTA for tennis) for paddle tennis?

Answer (score 1):

National and international Tournaments for Ranking only.

See here: http://www.padelfip.com/

jMike